# How to create generic yup object schema?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-hook-form, yup

I have working custom hook form that creates form with a given fields and validates them:

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";

export const useCustomForm = (schema: yup.AnyObject) => {
  const formSchema = yup.object(schema).required();

  interface FormFields extends yup.InferType<typeof formSchema> {}

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    getValues,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormFields>({
    resolver: yupResolver<FormFields>(formSchema),
  });

  const onFormSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent, onSubmit: () => void) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
  };

  return {
    register,
    onSubmit: onFormSubmit,
    getValues,
    errors,
  };
};
```

Having used in SignUpForm:

```
export const SignUpForm: FC<unknown> = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const { register, onSubmit, getValues, errors } = useCustomForm({
    username: yup.string().min(3).max(50).required(),
    password: yup.string().min(6).max(50).required(),
    password_confirmation: yup
      .string()
      .min(6)
      .max(50)
      .required()
      .oneOf([yup.ref('password')], 'Password does not match!'),
    is_admin: yup.string(),
  });

  ... other code
```

It works fine, but the problem is that typescript don't show form fields using getValue()

```
  const onSignUp = () => {
    const values = getValues();
    console.log(values.);
  };
```

I tried to pass generic type to useCustomForm:

```
export const useCustomForm = <T>(schema: yup.ObjectSchema<T>)
```

But don't sure which type should choose as schema and TS tells that

```
Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'Maybe<AnyObject>'.
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'AnyObject'
```

Any suggestions how to pass generic, so getValues() will be suggesting form fields?